# Angular 2 - Checking for server errors from subscribe

Tags: http, angular, subscribe

I feel like this scenario should be in the Angular 2 docs, but I can't find it anywhere.

Here's the scenario

1. submit a form (create object) that is invalid on the server
2. server returns a 400 bad request with errors I display on the form
3. after the subscribe comes back, I want to check an error variable or something (ie. if no errors > then route to newly created detail page)

I imagine it working something like this:

```
this.projectService.create(project)
    .subscribe(
        result => console.log(result),
        error => {
            this.errors = error
        }
    ); 
}

if (!this.errors) {
    //route to new page
}
```

I'm very new to Angular 2 so this may come from my lack of understanding in how an Observable works. I have no issue with displaying that data on the form, but can't figure out how to see it within the ts component. I really just want to check the success/fail of the http create.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

As stated in the relevant RxJS documentation, the [`.subscribe()` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) can take a third argument that is called on completion if there are no errors.

For reference:

> 1. `[onNext]` (`Function`): Function to invoke for each element in the observable sequence.
> 2. `[onError]` (`Function`): Function to invoke upon exceptional termination of the observable sequence.
> 3. `[onCompleted]` (`Function`): Function to invoke upon graceful termination of the observable sequence.

Therefore you can handle your routing logic in the `onCompleted` callback since it will be called upon graceful termination (which implies that there won't be any errors when it is called).

```
this.httpService.makeRequest()
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        // Handle result
        console.log(result)
      },
      error => {
        this.errors = error;
      },
      () => {
        // 'onCompleted' callback.
        // No errors, route to new page here
      }
    );
```

---

As a side note, there is also a [`.finally()` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md) which is called on completion regardless of the success/failure of the call. This may be helpful in scenarios where you always want to execute certain logic after an HTTP request regardless of the result (i.e., for logging purposes or for some UI interaction such as showing a modal).

> `Rx.Observable.prototype.finally(action)`
>
> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence terminates gracefully or exceptionally.

For instance, here is a basic example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

// ...

this.httpService.getRequest()
    .finally(() => {
      // Execute after graceful or exceptionally termination
      console.log('Handle logging logic...');
    })
    .subscribe (
      result => {
        // Handle result
        console.log(result)
      },
      error => {
        this.errors = error;
      },
      () => {
        // No errors, route to new page
      }
    );
```

Comment: Out of all the answers I found regarding error handling of observables, this is the best one. Thank you

Comment: Also keep in mind that http interceptors can be used to handle these errors in a more transversal way - https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-handle-http-errors-using-interceptors-5cc483103740 - so you dont have to handle them on each subscribe

Comment: This approach is deprecated now. https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Answer (score 22):

Please note that the previous syntax with callbacks has been deprecated as of 6.4 and is going to be removed with 8.0. Instead of

```
of([1,2,3]).subscribe(
    (v) => console.log(v),
    (e) => console.error(e),
    () => console.info('complete') 
)
```

you should now use

```
of([1,2,3]).subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.info('complete') 
})
```

https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Comment: Most reliable answer as of 2022. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve with following way

```
    this.projectService.create(project)
    .subscribe(
        result => {
         console.log(result);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errors = error
        }
    ); 
}

if (!this.errors) {
    //route to new page
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated rxjs way 2022

```
this.projectService.create(project)
    .subscribe({
      next: (data)=>console.log('data',data),
      error: (err)=>console.log('error',err),
      complete:()=>console.log('complete')
    });
```