# How to access component variables in subscribe method

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a loading spinner before a Service is called. If the service fails, it should hide the loading spinner.

I am able to show the spinner, but not able to hide it, because the component variables are not accessible in the subscribe method. Is there any way around this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { FoodService } from '../../../services/food.service';

import { Food } from '../../../interfaces/Food';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-food',
  templateUrl: './food.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./food.component.css']
})
export class FoodComponent implements OnInit {

  foodContents$: Observable<Food>
  public foodPageId : any;
  public spinnerStatus: boolean = false;
  public foodRequest;

  constructor(private foodService:FoodService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => this.foodPageId = res.id);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.foodRequest)
    {
      this.spinner.show();
      this.spinnerStatus = true;
      this.foodContents$ = this.foodService.GetFoodPageContent(this.foodPageId);
      this.foodContents$.subscribe({
        error(err) {
          /*Not able to access spinner and spinnerStatus variables.
          How to access these?*/
          this.spinner.hide();
          this.spinnerStatus = false;
        }
      }); 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback :)

Comment: Just console log `this` inside err and you'll see the scope is not pointing to what you think... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle error [like this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html) (the error handling function should be the second argument):

```
this.foodContents$.subscribe(()=>{},
 (err) => {
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.spinnerStatus = false;
  }
);
```

If you wanna use also `finnaly` (try-catch-finally) you can also put third function as last argument of subscribe('[onCompleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104835/860099)').

UPDATE

You can also try following approach (change `ngOnInit()` to `async ngOnInit()`)

```
try {
  let result= await this.foodService.GetFoodPageContent(this.foodPageId).toPromise()
  // ... process result
}
catch(err) {  
  this.spinnerStatus = false;
} 
finally {
  this.spinner.hide();
}
```

Comment: @Jake I update answer - I write code from head sorry

Comment: Is it possible to add a "finally" too in case there is no error, but I still want to hide the spinner?

Comment: I have idea to change `()=>{}` to `()=>{ this.spinner.hide(); }` (so inside data and error handlers you can call any other method e.g. this.myfinnal() )

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I would not go so far as saying handling `wrong way`. You can just use arrow functions to get the correct scope of `this`... Just a sidenote.

Answer (score 3):

Your `this` is not pointing to the correct scope.. check this:
[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

You can solve it by using arrow function:

```ts
  .subscribe({
    error: () => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.spinnerStatus = false;
    }
  });
```

With that, `this` is now pointing at the component, meaning you have access to your variables.

But I would do... to could call these in `finalize` (using rxjs 6) which is called despite error happening or success:

```ts
this.foodContents$.pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.spinnerStatus = false;
  })
 )
  .subscribe((data: SomeModel) => {
    // success, do something with data
  },
  (err) => {
    // error, do something..
 }));
```

Since usually we want to do also something else when error or success happens.