# Alert dialog cannot be read in error block

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to show alert dialog if login not success, but it not works. Do I do something wrong in my codes.

```
login(params) {
    this.presentLoader();

    return this.http
        .post(`${this.base_url}/login`, new HttpParams({
            fromObject: {
                'username': params.username,
                'password': params.password,
            }
        }))
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
                this.loader.dismiss();
                this.storage.set('access_token', response.access_token);
                this.storage.set('user_id', response.id);
                this.storage.set('username', params.username);
                this.storage.set('email', response.email);
                this.authState.next(true);
                //other codes

            },
            (error) => {
                this.presentError('Uh oh, Login failed!. Please try again');
            },
            () => {
                this.loader.dismiss();
            }
        );
}

private async presentLoader() {
    this.loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message: 'pls wait',
    });
    await this.loader.present();
}

private async presentError(message) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        message: message,
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

**i think its not read everything in the error block, but if i put alert dialog under loader.dismiss it works**

Comment: Check "this" scope inside presentError message. Also, your error fallback will only be called inside subscribe if your HTTP response code differs from 200, being any of 400 or 500 HTTP codes.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus i've tried to insert error in subscribe but still not working.

Comment: Inside the complete callback (the third subscribe function) you could check whether an error was thrown or not and try showing your dialog inside it.

Comment: My bad, you cannot check inside onCompleted callback if you got an error. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104629/angular-2-checking-for-server-errors-from-subscribe

Comment: @nurr did you tried to add await before the call to async func?
await this.presentError('Uh oh, Login failed!. Please try again');

Comment: @OdedBD how can i do that? can you show me how. thanks

Comment: When you call presentError in the error section try to add await, and I would have console.error in the error section as well to make sure your code did get to there

Comment: (error) => {

              **await** this.presentError('Uh oh, Login failed!. Please try again');
            },
hope it will work.. :)

Comment: @OdedBD i have tried it but its not working. btw, thanks for helping me. if you have another way, pls let me know.

Comment: @nurr gladly, let me know if this solution solved it so I will post it as an answer as well

Comment: Are you getting an error in the first place? You can check this by logging inside your error block.

Comment: i'm not getting any error. even i put **console.log(error)** , it seems dont read anything in my error block. @TomasVancoillie

Comment: Do you send an error back from your API? Does this `${this.base_url}/login` return an error with a HTTP response code of 500 for example?

Comment: If you can't send an error back, you can test your error block by changing the `correct` route to status code 500 and see if it comes back to the error block.

Comment: can you teach me how to change to status code 500? i'm still new about this. thank you. @TomasVancoillie